# Python: fast way to get position of all the element in a list in different lists given

Tags: python, arrays, list, search, indexing

I have a list of numbers of length 10, say

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Then, I have an matrix of size 35 * 10 which:

- `L[0]` (value 1) can be found in the first column of the matrix
- `L[1]` (value 2) can be found in the 2nd column of the matrix
- etc.

I would like the index for each value in `L` in the corresponding column in the matrix given.

I know how to do this for one value, but if say the list `L` is very long and the matrix is large, it might be slow, so wondering if there is a faster way of doing this.

Comment: Is your matrix in `numpy.ndarray` format, or is it a list of lists? Whatever you're doing, it sounds like you're going to want `numpy`.

Comment: @Mr.F numpy array of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [docs page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
a = np.random.ranint(0,50,(35,10))

# identify location of value in array that are in L
ix = np.in1d(a.ravel(), L).reshape(a.shape)
```

Now you just need to determine what to do with your newly-identified indices!

By that, I mean you can remove the "bad" values
    a[ix==False] = np.NAN

or operate on the "good" values exclusively
    a[ix] *= 25